# how to implement regex in Angular ng-select?

Tags: regex, angular

I have already implemented angular multi-select Dropdown. Now I want it to search using RegEx. Like if I have qwertyuiop, and if I wrote w*i than it should suggest me all the entries who contains 'W' and 'I' in the same string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to know the whole thing, like how to bind the input of an input field, read the input, create an RegEx out of it, and then use the RegEx as a filter to the list you are showing in your dropdown ?
Or only the RegEx part?

For the part with RegEx:

You should take a look at the Javascript Defintion of RegEx (for example at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) ). It has a quite nice functionality.

```
let input:string = // the value the user typed, like w*i
const regEx = new RegExp(input)

let myDropdownList:string[] = // the list of strings i want to filter
let filteredDropdownList = myDropdownList.forEach((value:string)=>{
    return regEx.test(value)
})
```

What happens here?
You are creating a regular Expressen with `new RegExp(someString)`.
You can optimize it with RegEx flags.
Later you test a string with `myRegEx.test(theString)`. It will return true if the regEx founds at least one match in the string.

I hope this helps you a bit.

warm regards.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do i need to add any thing in my ts expect this for regex?

Comment: let searchValue = event;
    console.log(searchValue);
    const searchWords = searchValue.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    let taskList: any = [];
    Object.assign(taskList, this.taskNamesFilter);
    
    taskList = taskList.filter(val => {
      return val.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue => {
        new RegExp(`${searchWords}`, "gi").test(taskList);
      });
    });                                                 i had this in my code.

Comment: The RegEx does not have to be created for each item.   
Also, you have to test the value ```val```not the whole list.   
===> So, first creating the RegEx and then call ```taskList.filter( val => myRegEx.test(val))```would be enough.

Comment: Whenever i worte * search result doesn't show any suggestions. :-(

Comment: In this case you should provide some more information. The relevant code parts for example.

Comment: This is in my .TS file.

`searchTaskName(event: any) {

 let searchValue = event;
 console.log(searchValue);
 const searchWords = searchValue.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
 let taskList: any = [];
 Object.assign(taskList, this.taskNamesFilter);
 const myRegEx = new RegExp(searchValue);

 taskList = taskList.filter(val => {

  return myRegEx.test(val);
 });

 console.log(searchValue);
 console.log(taskList);
 this.taskNameDropDown.items = taskList;

}`

Comment: and is in my .HTML file.
  
  `<ng-select
[multiple]="false"
name="taskNameDropDown"
#taskNameDropDown
[items]="filterTaskName"
placeholder="Search a Task with * in End"
(selected)="selectTaskToAddQuantity($event)"
(typed)="searchTaskName($event)"
></ng-select>`

Comment: :-) Perhaps formated as an edit in your question ? That would be nice

Comment: This works fine but the result is not rendered in the drop-down.